# Tarball on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, file-format

How do I extract bz2.tar tarballs on Windows 7? What program will do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suggest using [7-Zip:](http://www.7-zip.org/)

> Supported formats:
>
> - Packing / unpacking: 7z, XZ, **BZIP2**, GZIP, **TAR**, ZIP and WIM
> - Unpacking only: ARJ, CAB, CHM, CPIO, CramFS, DEB, DMG, FAT, HFS, ISO,    LZH, LZMA, MBR, MSI, NSIS, NTFS, RAR, RPM, SquashFS, UDF, VHD,
>     WIM,    XAR and Z.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> How do I extract bz2.tar tarballs on Windows 7?

Download 7-zip from [here](http://www.7-zip.org/) and extract the archive.

> What program will do it?

Without knowing the contents of the archive - pretty much impossible to say.

Comment: +1 for not posting a bare link...

Comment: @JNK: To be honest, I don't know how this post was any more helpful than the bare link...

Comment: @musicfreak (1) Link rot  (2) There's a second question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the second question is the same as the first. "What program will do it?" == "What program will extract tarballs on Windows?"

Comment: @musicfreak *shrugs* downvote if you don't like it.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote you, my point was that bare links aren't necessarily bad if they answer the question. Nothing wrong with your answer. :)

Comment: @Sathya While your answer is clearly more constructed, I find that sometimes brevity and overall "zen-nes" is overall better for didactic purposes. In other words, some questions are best answered with another question.

Comment: To clarify, the question was written in a manner of speech. The second intended to restate the first. One link was fine.

Answer (score 2):

[WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/) also handles TAR and TAR.GZ (tarball) formats.